# systemctl doesn't work when running from `docker run $image chroot` command (Bionic)

Tags: systemctl

1. Tested on fresh installed Ubuntu Bionic OS using http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso image. The release of Ubuntu via 'lsb_release -rd'

> ```
> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
> Release:  18.04
> ```

2. The version of the systemd package via 'apt-cache policy systemd'

> ```
> systemd:
>   Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.33
>   Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.42
>   Version table:
>      237-3ubuntu10.42 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
>      237-3ubuntu10.38 500
>         500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
>  *** 237-3ubuntu10.33 100
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>      237-3ubuntu10 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
> ```

3. Steps to reproduce the problem:

$ `sudo su`

$ `apt update`

$ `apt install docker.io`

$ `docker pull ubuntu:latest`

$ `docker run -it -v /:/host_root:ro ubuntu:latest chroot /host_root/ systemctl -a`

4. What you expected to happen: a list of all systemd units is expected to be displayed, e.g.

> ```
>   UNIT                                                                LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB       DESCRIPTION
>   proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount                                   loaded    active   waiting   Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Auto
>   dev-cdrom.device                                                    loaded    active   plugged   VBOX_CD-ROM
>   dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_CD\x2dROM_VB2\x2d01700376.device      loaded    active   plugged   VBOX_CD-ROM
> ....[cut out]....
> ```

5. What happened instead: get the following error message

> Failed to connect to bus: No data available

6. The same steps tested on fresh installed Ubuntu Xenial OS using http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso image.
   And in this environment, the `systemctl -a` command **works well**.

> ```
> $ lsb_release -rd
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
> Release:  16.04
> ```

> ```
> $ apt-cache policy systemd
> systemd:
>   Installed: 229-4ubuntu21.16
>   Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.29
>   Version table:
>      229-4ubuntu21.29 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
>      229-4ubuntu21.27 500
>         500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
>  *** 229-4ubuntu21.16 100
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>      229-4ubuntu4 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
> ```

7. Additional notes: I tried to add `--privileged` options to `docker run` command but it didn't help.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me: it is needed to add option `--pid host` option to `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

The "chroot" is misleading. It is just "systemctl" which does not work in such a docker container. That's a duplicate to about a hundred other questions on stackoverflow.

The systemctl command is a only wrapper trying to talk to the systemd daemon on PID 1. Use "ps -ax | less" on your host system that this is the case. The connection is done via the d-bus and that's where the error comes from. In a container the command after the "run" is put on PID 1 - so that "chroot" is there. Which is not good enough for systemctl.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the problem in enough detail.  
I don't need to run `systemctl ...` command in the container itself, but I need the result of running this command on the host. I can't run this command directly on the host.  
  
Thank you for explaining the details of the problem.  
  
P.S. I found a solution that works for me: it is needed to add option `--pid host` option to `docker run` command.